# How does code execute while assigning to variable

Tags: python

In this code:

```
something=input('insert something here')
something
```

Shouldn't the input call be made two times as output once as I assign input to the (something) variable and the second time as I call the (something) variable itself?

Comment: You're not assiging "call this function" to `something`, you're assigning the value that calling it returns.

Comment: You cannot "call" variables. You can only call functions.

Comment: I recommend [getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Comment: please do not keep adding unrelated comments into your question

Answer (score 0):

```
something=input('insert something here')
```

This doesn't assign a function. It *calls* a function. At this moment, the "work" of getting input from the user is being done. After this point, `something` is a string. A decided value. The fact that it came from the user (and not from, say, a file or a constant somewhere) is history. Lost to time. Forget about that; it's just a value now.

```
something
```

Oh, look! A string value! If we're in the Python REPL, this will print it out. Otherwise, it has no effect. If you want to print out a string as part of your Python *program*, you can do

```
print(something)
```

If you *want* to make `something` be a function that asks the user for input every time, you can do that.

```
def something():
  return input('insert something here')
```

But now you still have to make those calls explicit with parentheses. Python doesn't let you implicitly call functions.

```
# Ask for input twice
something()
something()
```